# How to use three.js to calculate the point after translate and reduce?

Tags: javascript, three.js, translate

I want to calculate the point A to H after rotate degrees and rotate to direction vector(-42,51,11) and let the point translate to point(-62,283,63) and reduce (66/151).

but when I first try to use`.add(-62,283,63)` and`.scale(66/151)` to calculate it did not run, then I try to let A to H plus(-62,283,63)and multiply (66/151) it also error,please help me.

Thank you in advance and please excause my bad english. Best regards.

```
const tree = [
    [   0,   0,   0],  // A
    [   2, 151,   2],  // B
    [ -62, 283,  63],  // C
    [  62, 296, -58],  // D 
    [-104, 334,  74],  // E
    [ -58, 338,  45],  // F
    [  67, 403, -55],  // G
    [ 105, 365, -86],  // H
  ] 

let axis = new THREE.Vector3(-42, 51, 11)
axis.normalize()
let matrix = new THREE.Matrix4()
let radians = 90 * Math.PI / 180
matrix.makeRotationAxis(axis, radians)
let newTree = []
for(const vector of tree) {
  // Define the vector3:
  let vec = new THREE.Vector3(vector[0], vector[1], vector[2])
  vec.applyMatrix4(matrix)
  newTree.push(vec.toArray()) 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Not the exact answer, but just some clarification.

[`.add()`](https://threejs.org/docs/index.html#api/en/math/Vector3.add) expects `THREE.Vector3()` in its parameter, so

```js
let transVector = new THREE.Vector3( -62, 283, 63);

let vectorA = new THREE.Vector3(tree[0][0], tree[0][1], tree[0][1]);
vectorA.add(transVector);
```

and to multiply a vector with a scalar value you need to use [`.multiplyScalar()`](https://threejs.org/docs/index.html#api/en/math/Vector3.multiplyScalar)

```js
vectorA.multiplyScalar(66/151);
```

Comment: @prisoner849Thank you for your answer sincerely.

Comment: @prisoner849Can you provided more details  about translate to point(-62,283,63)?